# How to make rectangle's border different?

Tags: html, css, responsive, figure

HTML:

```
<div class="rectangle">Some text</div>
```

CSS:

```
.rectangle {
    width: 300px;
    height: 80px;
    border: 5px solid red;
}
```

Is there any way to make div looks like in the photo?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [CSS Shapes](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/#0)

```css
#pointer {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
}

#pointer:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid white;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
}

#pointer:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid red;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="pointer">


</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) and [`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) to achieve the result.

```css
.rectangle {
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  border-right: none;
  position: relative;
}

/* for the triangular shape */
.rectangle::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right:-45px;
  bottom: 0;
  top:-5px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 45px solid red;
  border-top: 45px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 45px solid transparent;
  z-index:1000;
}


/* for hiding the portion except the border 
 of the triangle shape */
.rectangle::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right:-40px;
  bottom: 0;
  top:0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 40px solid white;
  border-top: 40px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 40px solid transparent;
  z-index:1001;
}
```

```html
<div class="rectangle">Some text</div>
```

---

In case you don't need border like structure then you can avoid [`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) portion and set background color to main div.

```css
.rectangle {
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  border-right: none;
  position: relative;
  background:red;
}

.rectangle::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right:-45px;
  bottom: 0;
  top:-5px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 45px solid red;
  border-top: 45px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 45px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="rectangle">Some text</div>
```

For more shapes refer : [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS)

Answer (score 1):

To keep only the border without filling the `div`, You can try using `::before` and `::after`.

Something like this:

```css
.rectangle {
   width: 200px;
   height: 40px;
   position: relative;
   border-top: 2px solid red;
   border-bottom: 2px solid red;
   border-left: 2px solid red;
   -moz-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
   border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
   margin-left: 50px;
}
.rectangle::after {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   left: 100%;
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   top: 2px;
   border-top: 18px solid transparent;
   border-left: 10px solid #fff;
   border-bottom: 17px solid transparent;
}
.rectangle::before {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   left: 100%;
   width: 0;
   top: -2px;
   height: 0;
   border-top: 22px solid transparent;
   border-left: 14px solid red;
   border-bottom: 22px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="rectangle">Some text</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider rotating a *pseudo-element* by declaring a `transform: rotate()` property value, as demonstrated in the code snippet embedded below.

As an alternative to achieving the same behaviour declaring `border` property rules, this method allows borders to be declared on the element in an intuitive manner using only one *pseudo-element*.

Rotating an element in this way also gives you the option to fill in the element with a solid colour - allowing you more freedom in customization.

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```css
.rectangle {
    width: 300px;
    height: 80px;
    border: 5px solid red;
    /* additional */
    border-right: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative; /* required */
}

/* Additional */
.rectangle:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    border-right: 5px solid red;
    border-top: 5px solid red;
    box-sizing: inherit;
    right: -28px;
    top: 7px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="rectangle">Some text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the pseudo class `after`

```css
.rectangle {
    position: relative;
    width:200px;
    height:40px;
    margin-left:40px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:red;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:40px;
}
.rectangle:after {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top:0px;
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
    border-top:20px solid transparent;
    border-left:40px solid red;
    border-bottom:20px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="rectangle">Some text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `:before` and `:after`

```css
.rectangle {
    width: 300px;
    height: 80px;
    border: 5px solid blue;
    border-right: none;
    position: relative;
}
.rectangle::before {
    content: '';
    border-top: 5px solid blue;
    width: 120px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -115px;
    bottom: 16px;
    transform: rotate(-21deg);
}
.rectangle::after {
    content: '';
    border-top: 5px solid blue;
    width: 120px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -115px;
    top: 16px;
    transform: rotate(21deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="rectangle">Some text</div>
```